# Can I add payload to Stackdriver calls to Opsgenie

Tags: stackdriver, opsgenie

We have integrated Stackdriver with Opsgenie, would like to pass some tags and values in the Stackdriver call payload to Opsgenie.
Can it be done?
Thanks so much,
Meir

Answer (score 0):

Opsgenie has a webhook integration with Google Stackdriver which sends incidents to Opsgenie API with detailed information. Once you add Google Stackdriver [integration](https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/google-stackdriver-integration#section-add-google-stackdriver-integration-in-opsgenie) in Opsgenie, follow the brief [instructions](https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/google-stackdriver-integration#section-configuration-in-google-stackdriver) to setup Opsgenie webhook on Google Stackdriver.

Keep in mind that once you paste the integration API URL into ENDPOINT URL as suggested in the steps, click 'Test Connection" before clicking save.

On the Opsgenie 'Integration' page, before clicking 'Save Integration', right above it there is 'Tags' you can set and 'Extra Properties' where you can add properties and their values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the data sent from Stackdriver to Opsgenie. Instead, you can use [Opsgenie's Alert Policies](https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/create-and-manage-global-alert-policies/) to modify the alerts based on the parsed data received from Stackdriver